# Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive. Here is an example of a case that is not matched

Tags: tree, ocaml

Why Leaf doesn't match in this part?

```
99 | ......match t with
100 |       | Node (Leaf, _, r) -> r
101 |       | Node (l, _, Leaf) -> l
102 |       | Node (l, _, r) ->
103 |         let newy = max l in
104 |         Node (remove newy l,newy, r)
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
Leaf
```

How to make it work?

Comment: ```
let rec remove x t =
  match t with 
  | Leaf -> Leaf
  | Node (l, y, r) -> 
    if x = y then
      match t with
      | Node (Leaf, _, r) -> r
      | Node (l, _, Leaf) -> l
      | Node (l, _, r) ->
        let newy = max l in
        Node (remove newy l,newy, r)
    else if x < y then 
      Node (remove x l, y, r)
    else (* x > y *) 
      Node (l, y, remove x r)
```

Comment: If you wish to amend your question, you can directly edit it, rather than trying to add code i comments.

Answer (score 3):

Your match has three alternatives that all start with `Node`. I don't think there's much question why there's no match for `Leaf`. If `t` is `Leaf`, it won't match any of the three patterns.